# process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cp file dir, ...) failed error while building application on eclipse and using cygwin

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to copy header files from source file dir to an include dir from Android.mk. I am building the application in eclipse running on top of windows but using cygwin to generate linux env. I am getting this error

> process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cp jni/core/source/serialize.h jni/core/include, ...) failed.

Android.mk file looks like:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ...
FILE_PATH := $(MY_JNI_DIR)/core/include/
FILE := $(MY_JNI_DIR)/core/source/serialize.h
$(shell cp $(FILE) $(FILE_PATH))
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add this line to your android.mk file see if it helps: 


LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/core/source

Comment: and this one: include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Answer (score 0):

Make cannot find "cp.exe".
I solved my problem by adding "${GIT_FOLDER}/usr/bin/" to my path. There was a cp.exe file.